# .map is not a function with Styled Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, map-function

I have this small code block that returns the error:

"TypeError: object.attributeCollection.first.map is not a function"

```
      <StyledRow>
        {object.attributeCollection.first.map((attribute) => (
          <LabelAssistant attribute={attribute} />
        ))}
      </StyledRow>
```

The object in the console looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

Comment: first is an object and not an array so Map is indeed not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is an [Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `first` being a `StringAttributeModel` is not an Array.